# Use of logo, trademark and brand

Tags: trademark

Let's say **X** develops an app that tracks injuries of players who play in the NFL...

## Questions

> 1. Can **X** legally name the app ***NFL Injury Tracker***? (...without infringing on any trademarks, etc.?)
> 2. What restrictions would there be on **X**'s use of the NFL logo in the app's marketing materials?
> 3. What if **X** uses a logo slightly resembling the NFL logo but is not the same as the NFL logo?

[image: NFL Logo]

[image: Possible app logo (to be adapted)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NFL can prohibit X from using its trademarks, or markings that would be [likely to confuse](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/webaka/html/Likelihood/Likelihood_of_Confusion.html) a reasonable person, in any of X's business marketing.

The NFL's shield wordmark has USPTO registration number 4682232 (deep links aren't allowed, but their search engine is [here](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=login&p_lang=english&p_d=trmk).) The images you've added don't seem alike enough to be confusing to me (I don't think I'd be mistaking one for the other), but in a lot of settings the app name will have only text, not an image.  Then you get at the trademark issue for the term "NFL" itself.

NFL can trademark that three-letter sequence, and there are good reasons for them being able to keep control of that trademark to authenticate sourcing.  For example, if I said "this hamburger is from McDonalds" you have certain expectations about it based on the brand, and McDonalds the company has a legally protected interest in preventing me from saying that if it wasn't true.  I have no right to put that 9-letter sequence on my burger joint without a license from the corporate giant.

Similarly, The NFL has a legally protected interest in preventing somebody from advertising or implying that an information source or the information contained therein is licensed and/or an official source of information, if that's not true.  A reasonable person might expect that an information source about NFL player injuries, with "NFL" in its name, would be an official licensed source of that information; the real NFL can seek an injunction and/or penalties if that's not actually the case.  "Pro Football Player Injury Tracker" might not carry the same expectation.

At the bottom of [NFL.com](http://www.nfl.com/), they claim, emphasis added, that "**NFL and** the NFL shield design are registered trademarks of the National Football League." So they have put folks on notice they intend to defend that three-letter sequence as theirs, at least for all subjects related to professional American football.

[Sean Mullin says](http://www.ehow.com/list_6647869_nfl-super-bowl-trademark-regulations.html) "The NFL is notorious for guarding its intellectual property rights to the full extent of the law."  X should probably spend some time with an IP lawyer.

If you're asking if it's *possible* for X to legally use the NFL's trademark, the short answer is **yes**.  It is possible for X to license use of the trademark from the NFL so long as the NFL is willing to grant/sell the license on terms that X also agrees to.

See [this prequalification page](https://www.nfl.info/NFLConsProd/Welcome/cpAgreement.htm) linked to from [this law firm's website](http://www.legalteamusa.net/tacticalip/2013/10/25/the-nfl-and-trademarks/), or click "Become a Licensee" [here](https://www.nfl.info/NFLConsProd/Welcome/index.html) to see that in context.

Comment: Still seeking more answers. This answer does not address all the subtleties of the question. For example, in this scenario: 1. **X** does not seek to use the NFL logo. But the acronym *NFL* is in the title. Surely, the three letters in sequence: N, F and L can not be protected? Can it? 2. [The real NFL logo might be this](http://bloguin.com/awfulannouncing/wp-content/uploads/sites/94/2014/01/nfllogo.jpg). And the app might [adapt a logo that looks more like this](http://www.nfl-motorcycle.co.uk/image/nfl-logo.jpg). Would that be a problem? What trademark law **principles** are in play here?

Comment: Answer edited.  In short: 1. Yes it can. 2. Consider editing your question to put those images in; you can use <img src="imageURL" /> tags or the GUI editor to put in images.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that **NFL** Injury Tracker might fall under the same use as the [Playboy case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playboy_Enterprises,_Inc._v._Welles).

> The Court held that nominative use (a type of fair use for discussing
> the product itself) is permitted where:
>
> The product or service can not be readily identified without using the
> trademark (i.e. trademark is descriptive of a person, place, or
> product attribute);
>
> Only so much of the mark may be used as is reasonably necessary for
> identification (e.g. the words may be reasonably used but not the
> specific font or logo); and
>
> The user does nothing to suggest sponsorship or endorsement by the
> trademark holder - which applies even if the nominative use is
> commercial.
>
> Here, the Ninth Circuit Court applied the nominative fair use test to
> the defendant and concluded the Defendant’s use of these trademarked
> items was permissible because there was **no other practical way for the
> Defendant to describe herself**.

If someone is tracking injuries in the NFL, I hope a court would find that there is no other practical way to describe the data source than to refer to the NFL. I would think that they should **not** use the logo at all as this fails the "only so much of the mark may be used" test.

As for number three, confusion was addressed by another answer.

Comment: Would a phrase like "Pro football" in place of "NFL" communicate the same thing to most of the audience without using the trademark?

Comment: No because there is more than one professional football league.

Comment: Any nearly as popular as NFL, in the US?  Also, might this lead X to expand their market?

Comment: I don't know enough about football leagues, there is probably a football stack where you could ask!